# Return averages from a List<T> as a single T object

Tags: java, list, generics, java-8, java-stream

I was wondering is there is a way to use stream to get a single `T` object from a `List<T>` with averages for double values and min for date. I have like 20 properties and maybe there is also a way to go through all of them automatically and with an if the property is a double to get an average, if is a date to get a min?

```
id     date                     value
3470,  2018-11-15 08:10:00+02,  25,101610.0234375
3467,  2018-11-15 07:53:00+02,  33,101398.984375
3468,  2018-11-15 07:54:00+02,  25,101599.765625
3549,  2018-12-28 18:20:00+02,  29.21
3550,  2018-12-28 18:24:00+02,  29.21
3551,  2018-12-28 18:27:00+02,  42.21
3552,  2019-01-07 09:42:00+02,
3553,  2019-01-07 09:50:00+02,  15.140000343323
3554,  2019-01-07 09:52:00+02,  -1.3799999952316
3555,  2019-01-07 10:03:00+02,  14.949999809265
```

Comment: You want to perform two different operations on two different attributes. It's possible with two iterations. Give it a try at least.

Comment: Is T bounded in any way? What is the average of two [`FieldPrototypeNotificationDistributedAttribute`](https://projects.haykranen.nl/java/)s ?

Comment: I used T for didactic purposes, it's an actual class.

Comment: What about `id`? It’s neither double nor date…

Comment: Id is Integer..

Answer (score 2):

From your description the only thing that pops to my head is reflection.

You can also define a downstream function:

```
BinaryOperator<T> downstream = (t1, t2) -> new T(t1.getValue() + t2.getValue(), ..., t1.getDate().isBefore(t2.getDate()) ? t1.getDate() : t2.getDate());
```

And then reduce:

```
T aggregate = list.stream().reduce(downstream).get();
T result = new T(aggregate.getValue() / list.size(), aggregate.getDate(), ...)
```

P.S.1: Note, that this has quite an overhead as it creates a new object in `BinaryOperator`, so this might not be the best solution when list is large.

P.S.2: This is a draft, I assumed you're using `LocalDateTime` to store `date` field, this is dependent on what you're using.

P.S.3: You need to define an aggregation method for your fields, for example `id`.

P.S.4: As @Aaron pointed out - I'm calculating the sum for `value` field, so that I can then divide it by the length of result, this way the average is correctly calculated.

Comment: I don't think the `/2` will lead to a correct average (because one of the operand is already the average of multiple values). It might be easier to use the reduction to produce a sum, then divide the final result by the number of elements in the original collection outside of the stream

Comment: P.S.5 that style of writing is a bit annoying

Comment: I need to add Id into the ecuation because it is primary key  in the table :/

Comment: Also some of the values are null, I can't divide the aggregate to the list.size() :(

Comment: you can validate by simply adding `filter` after `stream`

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [teeing collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) which was introduced in Java 12. In worst case you can copy/paste the implementation (as was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537663/8198056))

```
Result result = stream.collect(Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.mapping(T::getDate, Collectors.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())),
            Collectors.averagingDouble(T::getValue),
            Result::new
    ));
```

where result is a class defined by you

```
class Result {
    Optional<LocalDate> minDate;
    double avg;
    //all args constructor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient and clean solution is to use the `Stream::reduce` method and define a customer reduce function that performs `min` for specific fields and `average` for other fields depending on what you need.

```
list.stream().reduce(initialValue, (accumulator, listElement) -> reduceFunction(accumulator, listElement))
```

There's a slight difficulty here in that you need to know the length of the list to compute the average. So in order for the reduce function to be generic, the accumulator class has to have an element counter.